# Frames navigation via aspx server-side

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to do some frames navigation which must be made through aspx server-side.

Here's a simple example of what i'm trying to do:

**pg1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="pg1.aspx.vb" Inherits="pg1" %>
<html>
<body>
    <frameset>
        <frame src="pg2.aspx" id="pg2"/>
        <frame src="pg3.aspx" id="pg3"/>
    </frameset>
</body>
</html>
```

**pg2.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="pg2.aspx.vb" Inherits="pg2" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        alert(parent.frames['pg3'].frames['pg5'].location.href);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:LinkButton id="lkBt" runat="server"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**pg2.vb**

```
Public Partial Class pg2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub lkBt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lkBt.Click
        Response.Write("<script>" & vbCrLf)
        Response.Write("parent.frames['pg3'].frames['pg5'].location.href = 'pg6.aspx';")
        Response.Write(vbCrLf & "</script>")
    End Sub

End Class
```

**pg3.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="pg3.aspx.vb" Inherits="pg3" %>
<html>
<body>
    <frameset>
        <frame src="pg4.aspx" id="pg4"/>
        <frame src="pg5.aspx" id="pg5"/>
    </frameset>
</body>
</html>
```

**pg6.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="pg6.aspx.vb" Inherits="pg6" %>
<html>
<body>
    <p>pg6</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is in pg2.vb, when response writes, i get a javascript error saying:

> parent.frames.pg3.frames.pg5.location.href is null or not an object

Which is strange because as you can see in pg2.aspx, i've put a test alert of the same href:

> alert(parent.frames['pg3'].frames['pg5'].location.href);

Which alerts the expected link without any error.

This seems to be related to the response.write context where aspx runs, i say this because in the browser's debug, when i'm stopped at the breakpoint generated by pg2.vb response write error, in the pages/script selection there's only pg2.aspx.
But when i'm debugging and set a breakpoint at pg2.aspx head>script>alert, i can see all the pages in the selector.

Does anyone have any clue, on how can i make the lkBt_click>Response.Write, run on the context of all the pages?